# emacs artist mode does not work

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs24, emacsw32

I am using ergoemacs for windows downloaded from http://ergoemacs.org/index.html. The version is as follows:

GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2012-08-29 on MARVIN ErgoEmacs distribution 2.0.0.

The artist mode does not work. I would like to use it in org-mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to stop using some badly-supported emacs pseudo-fork, download the latest official release, and (probably) find that everything works much better.